# Near matches not found in CONTAINSTABLE

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, full-text-search, containstable

I am using **<kbd>SQL Server 2008</kbd>**

### DDL

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[t](
    [words] [varchar](1000) NULL,
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

### DML

```
insert into t(words)values('this is my laptop')
insert into t(words)values('this does not contains headphone')
```

### SQL Query

```
SELECT *
FROM 
t as t
JOIN CONTAINSTABLE(t, words,'"headphone*"', 10) fulltextSearch
ON
t.Id = fulltextSearch.[KEY]
```

### Results

No record found

I am expecting one records. Any Idea?

Comment: so, which version of sql server are you using? you've tagged both 2005 and 2008. the team brought fts into the engine between these two versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'this' is very likely a noise word (like 'the', 'and', etc), so it would not be included in the index. Try searching for one of the real words in your text.

-- EDIT --

Ok, that wasn't it...

I tried your code and it worked as expected for me - the query returned one record. The only difference is that I defined [id] as the primary key (which you must have done as well, or you couldn't create the index). I am betting your index is not populated - in SSMS, right click on the table, select 'full text index' -> 'start full population'.

Comment: +1 'this' is very likely a noise word (like 'the', 'and', etc), so it would not be included in the index.